# Troubleshooting ADB.exe "Device Offline" Issue

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[This is the screeshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T8kv.png)

I have installed all the latest versions of flutter and android studio, also reinstalled Android sdk and run commands adb kill-server and adb start-server, despite taking these steps to address the problem, I continue to experience the "Device Offline" issue when working with ADB.

Comment: Try a different USB cable, a different USB port and if you can a different phone to test if it is a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps to solve this issue:

1. Disconnect and reconnect your Android device.
2. Ensure that USB debugging is enabled on your Android device.
3. Try using a different USB cable or USB port.
4. Run the following command in your terminal to reset ADB:

   ```
   adb kill-server
   adb start-server
   ```
5. If you're using an emulator, try restarting the emulator.

Comment: I'm facing this issue in virtual device, iam using latest version of flutter 3.13.3 and android studio giraffe 2022.3.1.19.

Comment: Hi @Fakhr E Alam I have exactly the same problem, did you found any solution? Can you help me, please?